# Change label text at runtime in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, label, wpf-controls

I have one label named as `lblMsg`.

I want to change it's content runtime dynamically.

Below is the example of my code not the actual code. My for loop contains so many code and it takes approx 8 to 9 seconds on each loop. So it should be visible on UI.

For ex.

```
for(int i=0;i<=length;i++)
{
    lblMsg.Content="Test"+i;
}
```

But it is not working. Can any one help me with it?

Comment: For loop works instantly. if you want to see it updating by the time start with adding a timer and put i++ on the timer tick

Comment: It probably does update, but it goes way too fast for you to notice (probably less then one milisecond).

Comment: Instantly? One millisecond?  For all we know `length = int.MaxValue`.  UIs are going to hate that and if Telerik is involved well...better get out _War and Peace_

Comment: @MickyD Like I said twice, probably. Not definitely.

Comment: @FreekW. Like I implied, if `length` is a large value then his app will **appear to hang**.  Maybe I need better metaphors?

Comment: The above code is just an exmaple. My actual code takes time to execute .. approax 8-9 secinds on each. And my label should change accordingly like. Task 1 completed on first loop, task 2 completed on second loop etc.

Comment: Another way to resolve it by using Application.DoEvents(). I solved my issue by implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display a label with a incrementing number you can create a Task and then use a delay (Thread.Sleep()) to give the UI time to refresh the label.

Because you cannot change UI Elements within a separate Thread, you have to update the UI with the UI Dispatcher.

Sample Code

```
var length = 1000;

Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
            lblMsg.Content = "Test" + i;
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Inter-thread marshalling over the message pump is costly. Why not just use a timer?

Comment: So without dispatcher I can't update the label on runtime?

Comment: @Ripal you can, but you have to give the UI some time to refresh. As MickyD mentioned you can do this with a timer.